# How to pass variables from view to controller without form in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

i have these values in the view folder.
.blade file is

```
@foreach($nam as $ergebnisse)
<h3>Id:{{$ergebnisse->id}}
Name_Id:{{$ergebnisse->name_id}}
Geometrie_Id:{{$ergebnisse->geometrie_id}}
</h3>
<h3>

  <li>{{$ergebnisse->probe}}</li>
  <li>{{$ergebnisse->schnittgrosse}}</li>
  <li>{{$ergebnisse->temperatur}}</li>
  <li>{{$ergebnisse->zeit}}</li>
  <li>{{$ergebnisse->aussehen}}</li>
  <li>{{$ergebnisse->farbe}}</li>
  <li>{{$ergebnisse->deformation}}</li>
  <li>{{$ergebnisse->geruch}}</li>
  <li>{{$ergebnisse->texture}}</li>



</h3>

 @endforeach
```

now i want to make another query in terms of these parameters.so how can i pass these to the controller or is there any other way of generating the queries within the view and displaying them?

Comment: Harron if i'm not wrong you want fire another query using above values?

Comment: yes exactly. I want to fire another query

Comment: Harron then you should perform queries in model itself then passed it view from controller using `compact('data' ,'2ndqueryresult')`

Comment: can you plz help me how can i access all the rows of $nam within the controller.thanks

Comment: thanks SoftwareDev for your comment. public function getErgebnisse(){ $GEM=1; $name =1;$nam=Ergebnisse::where('name_id', $name) ->where('geometrie_id', $GEM) ->get(); return view('pages.ergebnisse')->with('nam',$nam);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, so i have 2 possible solutions:

1. If you want to load another view you can do something like this:

You can send parameters with links no need to be a form.

so you can do something like `<a href="your-url/{{$nam->id}}">Do stuff</a>`

This will send the id of your $nam object to the route you prefer.

your route will look like this:

```
Route::get('your-url/{$nam}', YourController@test);
```

And in your controller you have to catch this value

```
public function test(Nam $nam) {
  return $nam;
}
```

2. If you want to load the same view and have 2 different queries, just
   do the 2 different queries inside your controller and send them
   trough seperatly.

So in your current controller:

```
public function index(){
 $nam = Nam::all();
// this is your second query:
$nam2 = Nam::latest()->get();

return view('your-view', compact('name','nam2' //this is the second variable))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am new to web development and especially laravel.the problem is that rows can be varied upto 8 according to the selection by the users, so total params can be upto 72 or more.is that a good idea to pass 72 params  with link. I were thinking that there might be some way or hack to pass the whole array and to get that in the controller. i know its not something that is related to mvc.

Comment: you can pass any type of parameter in the link. so if you want to pass a array just pass it . the $nam->id i wrote is just an example. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters